# Python to PHP | String to Multidimensional Json Object To Array

Tags: php, python, arrays, object

I have a python script which returns an object as string. I call this python script with php and then print out the result with `var_dump(json_decode($result))` and get this (this it the right object I want so my python code works properly I guess):

> string(467) "{"userData": {"geburtsdatum": "PMS_2018-01-01", "anrede": "PMS_Herr", "ID": "1", "nachname": "PMS_Nachname1", "Test": {"tel": "PMS_Tel1", "postalOptIn": 0, "postal": "S3_Postal1", "email": "PMS_EMail1"}, "vorname": "PMS_Vorname1" }} "

So as you can see its a string on php side. 
But how can I convert it to an object now and the create a multidimensional array from it in php?

If you need more information pls ask Ill add it.

I tried:

```
json_decode($result, true);
json_decode($result);
$response = (array) $result;
```

all I get is an Array with 1 Index and the whole Object as Value in it.

The Object gets generated like this on python side:

```
for message in consumer:
        if message.key == str.encode(sys.argv[1]):
            returnValue = message.value #this here is an byte obj from external system

consumer.close()

print(returnValue.decode("latin-1"))
```

**Edit 2 and Solution**

After long search I found out that the service I'm using (3d Party) returns the result from the python script with `json_encode()`. I removed that and now this code works:

```
$array = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    return var_dump($array);
```

Comment: "No matter what I try"  Please show exactly what it is that you've tried and show the related results.

Comment: @PatrickQ Added Information so please remove -1 thanks :)

Comment: If the result *after* `json_decode()` is a string, the string you got back from python seems to have been encoded twice / is somehow malformed. What does `$result` contain exactly and how do you generate it?

Comment: @jeroen added information

Comment: Your first attempt (`json_decode($result, true);`) works just fine.  See [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bed675c2959b607b31eb4fee05f59386c8105d7).  It is unclear exactly what you're expecting, but the result is a multi-dimensional array that matches the JSON string given.

Comment: GMTA @PatrickQ, I even used PHP sandbox for my test.

Comment: @PatrickQ doesnt work added information

Comment: What, exactly, do you get back from the Python, without a var_dump()?

Comment: I think you need to provide more of the code that you're running. Because what you are saying is happening simply doesn't match what the code you say is being run.  Also, `return var_dump($array);` might not do what you expect, as `var_dump()` directly outputs the result. The `return` would then be returning `null`

Comment: Sloved it. Added information. Thanks guys for helping me. @jeroen you were right with double encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a string you can decode it like this:

```
$string =  '{"userData": {"geburtsdatum": "PMS_2018-01-01", "anrede": "PMS_Herr", "ID": "1", "nachname": "PMS_Nachname1", "Test": {"tel": "PMS_Tel1", "postalOptIn": 0, "postal": "S3_Postal1", "email": "PMS_EMail1"}, "vorname": "PMS_Vorname1" }}';

print_r(json_decode($string, true));
```

Which returns an array:

```
Array
(
    [userData] => Array
        (
            [geburtsdatum] => PMS_2018-01-01
            [anrede] => PMS_Herr
            [ID] => 1
            [nachname] => PMS_Nachname1
            [Test] => Array
                (
                    [tel] => PMS_Tel1
                    [postalOptIn] => 0
                    [postal] => S3_Postal1
                    [email] => PMS_EMail1
                )

            [vorname] => PMS_Vorname1
        )

)
```

Comment: doesnt work for me still returns `string() "object"`

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Both @PatrickQ and I were not able to replicate your issue. What, *exactly*, do you get back from the Python, without a `var_dump()`?

Comment: sloved it now. Thanks for helping. it was double encoded from my webservice which broke my object.